# how to reload password in dbcp basic datasource

Tags: aws-secrets-manager, apache-commons-dbcp, dbcp, tomcat-dbcp

dbcp2 basic datasource is being used for one of our java applications and database password is set by calling this [setter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.html#setPassword-java.lang.String-)

```
setPassword(final String password)
```

passwords are stored in AWS secrete manager, and now there is a password rotation logic build for the database, so now whenever a password is rotated my application fails to authenticate DB, I need to redeploy my application bypassing the new password.

I can read the latest password within the application but I don't see any callback APIs to refresh the password after expiry in dbcp.

Is there any option in DBCP to refresh the password without redeploying the application?